# Exportar a formato .csv en postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv

Estoy intentando exportar el resultado de un comando `psql` (PostgreSQL) en consola a un fichero .csv, el cual debe enviarse por correo electrónico.

Ahora mismo, mi sentencia es:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/ psql -h ${RSHOST} -p 5439 -U ${RSUID} ${RSDB} -A -F "," -P "footer=off" -c "select query as idquery,wlm_start_time as inicio,queue_time as tiempo_en_cola_microseg,exec_time as tiempo_ejecucion_microseg,(tiempo_en_cola_microseg+tiempo_ejecucion_microseg) as tiempo_total_microseg ,state as estado,mod(cast(floor(tiempo_total_microseg/3600000000) as integer),24) || ':' || mod(cast(floor(tiempo_total_microseg/60000000) as integer),60) || ':' || mod(cast(floor(tiempo_total_microseg/1000000) as integer),60)  as duracion_hhmmss,case tiempo_total_microseg when tiempo_total_microseg>28800000000 then 'CRITICAL' else 'WARNING' end as situacion from stv_wlm_query_state where tiempo_total_microseg >= 14400000000;" > /powercenter/amazon-redshift-utils/src/AdminScripts/monitoring/queriesconcola.csv
```

El problema es que el fichero .csv que llega no respeta las columnas, si no que pinta los campos así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que las columnas se respeten para que cuando el usuario final abra el .csv pueda visualizarlo correctamente.

¿Qué parámetros debo incluir en el `psql`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El formato CSV separa los campos por comas (o por el delimitador que especifiques), no esperes ver columnas, es texto plano. Las columnas las verás cuando importes ese fichero en una hoja de cálculo, en una base de datos o lo leas desde un programa que construya una tabla con los datos que contiene.

Me alegra comunicarte que no tienes tal problema, estás generando el CSV correctamente.

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de haberlo abierto con doble click y el sistema lo abrió con un editor de texto plano o la misma Excel, que ya me ha abierto en más de una ocasión un CSV así, tal cual. Aunque entiendo que, si lo exporta, sera para dárselo a alguien que se lo ha pedido en CSV y está generando el CSV que le han pedido correctamente. ¿Lo entiendes de otra forma?

Comment: Ahora, tu respuesta me gusta mas ;)

Comment: He conseguido más o menos lo que buscaba utilizando como delimitador en la consulta el punto y coma (;). De esta manera, al abrir el fichero `.csv`con doble click, excel respeta las columnas.

Comment: Estupendo, está bien saberlo, a veces Microsoft tiene sus cosillas... En cualquier caso, ambos son ficheros en formato CSV válidos. Afortunadamente no dependemos de lo que los desarrolladores de Excel decidan, aunque indirectamente nos afecte... :)